# Read serial port from micaz

Tags: c, linux, makefile, contiki

I would like to know if there is a mean to read in a terminal outputs generated by a MicaZ (printf), I tried the command: `make login` but it doesn't work.

I think that the is no rule `login` in micaz makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try command:

```
sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB1
```

Before doing this, check that your Micaz is connected through `ttyUSB1`.
You can check it using command:

```
ls /dev
```

If `ttyUSB1` is in the list above, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I need some explanation. when I uploaded the program I used `/dev/tyyUSB0`, why do I must use `/dev/tyyUSB1` to read from the mote?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the MIB510 board, used to program the MicaZ, has two serial ports. One for ISP and the other as a serial console. You might also want to use `minicom` to be able to fully interact with the serial console. On ubuntu you can install it with `sudo apt-get install minicom` and is run with `minicom -8 -b9600 -D/dev/ttyUSB1` set the baudrate according to your setup.
[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Minicom) you can find an introduction to minicom.

Good luck!